# Upload a file to webserver from local web application

Tags: php, r, shiny

My company has some local internet application run by Shiny (R Shiny). It is basically an application that generates and runs a simple HTML website locally.

Is it possible to use php in a local application to upload a file to our company server?

Comment: Well the question is rather is it possible to upload it from one local php installation to upload a file to a server in the internet?

Comment: Hey there. I tried to clarify your question, mostly by removing unnecessary context. I understand you basically want to know how to upload a file to a web server using php. I'd say it is possible. Good luck with that :)